# Select by given variable

Tags: javascript, meteor, graphql, apollo-server

My mongo db data:

```
{
    username: 'gemmi',
    age: 14,
    id: 'xsxsxsxsxss'
}
```

type Query:

```
{
  type Query {
    getUser(id: String, username: String): User
  }
}
```

resolver

```
getUser(root, args) {
  return Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: args.id, username: args.username });
},
```

My question is how I can get user by given variable?

So it should return user when i type:

```
getUser(id: "xsxsxsxsxss", username:"gemmi") { username _id }
```

and also when I type:

```
getUser(username:"gemmi") { username _id }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the `id` with `_id` in the `Query`

```
{
    type Query {
        getUser(_id: String, username: String): User
    }
}
```

And then you could simply use the `args` parameter to perform `findOne` call

```
getUser(root, args) {
    return Meteor.users.findOne(args);
}
```

The `args` object depends on how you performed the `query` call. You should remember about replacing `id` with `_id` in your calls. In the first case, when you did `getUser(_id: "xsxsxsxsxss", username:"gemmi")`, then `args` object is `{ _id: 'xsxsxsxsxss', username: 'gemmi' }`, however in second case, when you want to use `getUser(username:"gemmi")`, the `args` object is `{ username: 'gemmi' }`, so in both cases you can use it as a query lookup in the `findOne` method call.

Comment: Thank You, this is what I ment :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a input type for your query. And let meteor search for the respective user.

It could look like this:

Query:

```js
`
type User {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
}
input UserInput {
  id: ID
  username: String
}
type Query {
  getUser(user: UserInput!): User!
}
`
```

Resolver:

```js
...

getUser(root, { user }) {
  return Meteor.users.findOne(user);
}

...
```